# Implementing Matrix operations in C++

Tags: c++, math, matrix, c++17, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a simple C++ header-only library that implements some basic numerical algorithms. It's a hobbyist project, that I wish to do in my personal time.

I created a C++ `MatrixX` class that represents dynamic-size matrices, that is its dimensions can be supplied at run-time. Say, we create a `MatrixX` object as follows :

```cpp
MatrixXd m {
{1, 0, 0},
{0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1}
};
```

My `MatrixX<scalarType>` templated class uses `std::vector<scalarType>` as the container to store data.

Currently, if I write `m.row(i)`, it returns the i'th row vector of the matrix. What I'd also like is, to be able to have `m.row(i)` on the left-hand side of an assignment statement. Something like:

```
m.row(i) = {{1, 2, 3}};
m.row(j) = m.row(j) - 2*m.row(i);
```

Does anyone have any hints/tips on how to go about this task in C++? I am including my source code, unit tests and documentation as links below, and not pasting it inline for the sake of brevity.

- [Documentation](https://quantophile.github.io/mathlib/api-doc/)
- [Source code](https://github.com/quantophile/mathlib/blob/main/src/MatrixX.h)
- [Unit Tests](https://github.com/quantophile/mathlib/blob/main/tests/tests.cpp)

Comment: I took a peek at your code and those `row` and `col` functions are really expensive since they copy all the data out. Return an iterator begin/end pair instead. The iterator could point directly into the data and include a stepping variable, which would be `1` for row iterators and `cols()` for column iterators. Very cheap. Very little overhead. You could have `const` and non-`const` iterators to support `const` and non-`const` versions of `row` and `col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach for this type of situation is to have the `row()` method return a proxy object that represents the row without being the row itself.

You are then free to implement how this `RowProxy` behaves by having its operations inspect and maninupulate the matrix it was created from.

Here's a rough starting point:

```
template<typename T>
class RowProxy {
public:
  template<std::size_t N>
  RowProxy& operator=(const std::array<T, N>& rhs) {
    assert(N == row_index_.columns());
    // ...
  }

  RowProxy& operator=(const RowProxy& rhs) {
    assert(matrix_.columns() == rhs.matrix_.columns());
    // ...
  }

  RowProxy& operator=(const Vector<T>& rhs) {
    assert(matrix_.columns() == rhs.matrix_.columns());
    // ...
  }

  Vector<T>& operator*(const T& scalar) const {
    return ...;
  }

  // more operators...

private:
  MatrixX<T>& matrix_;
  std::size_t row_;
  
  template<typename T>
  friend class MatrixX;

  RowProxy(MatrixX<T>& m, std::size_t r) : matrix_(m), row_(r) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct MatrixX {
public:
  // ...
  
  RowProxy<T> row(std::size_t index) {
    return RowProxy<T>{*this, index};
  }

  // ...
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& operator*(const T& scalar, const RowProxy* rhs) const {
    return rhs * scalar;
}
```